# How do I create a Macro that adds shapes in a particular colour and groups them?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Please can you assist? I'm trying to create a button on Excel that once clicked opens UserForm1 (via a macro that has the command UserForm1.Show).

Thereafter, I want the userform to present options. These options will then (when selected create 2 rectangular shapes and group them. Take a look at some screenshots below along with macro recording code(too specific).

Ultimate objective: I want to create stickies on Excel. I've created 2 blocks and want to group them together everytime. So whenever I click on a button it creates a sticky for me :)

The error I get is

> The item with specified name was not found

Code for the 2 options on the form:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 285, 74.25, 112.5, 108.75). _
        Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.6000000238
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 285.75, 74.25, 111.75, 21.75). _
        Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Range("J11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 23")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 23", "Rectangle 24")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 286.5, 74.25, 111, 108.75). _
        Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent5
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 285.75, 74.25, 111.75, 18.75). _
        Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent5
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle21")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle21", "Rectangle22")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select
End Sub
```

[code as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsCB3.png)

User Form and end product:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. See [ask].

Comment: And please explain (1) what your code already does (what is working) (2) what is going wrong in your code and what do you expect instead (3) where exactly did you get stuck? (4) did you get any errors? If so where and which?

Comment: Okay sure. Thanks for letting me know. I'll post it as text as well :)

Comment: So, what's happening is that I get a debug message when I run it and doesnt group the 2 rectangles together to create a "sticky". I suspected this may be because the code is specifically describing "rectangle21" instead of a variable? Not sure.

Comment: The error I get is " The item with specified name was not found"

Comment: You get this error because everytime you add a shape, name changes, so yeah, your code should get the name of the new shape in a variable. You are right.

Comment: @ Foxfire And Burns And Burns, Any idea how I could code it such that it would get the name of the new shapes created and select that to group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use variables `Shape1` and `Shape2` to remember the new added shapes. Note that you have to use `.OLEFormat.Object` and cannot directly access the item like you can with `Selection` (which is a bit odd by Excel).

This way you can get independent from the hard coded shape names.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' instead I recommend to reference a worksheet 
                                       ' by name: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")

    Dim Shape1 As Shape
    Set Shape1 = sht.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 285, 74.25, 112.5, 108.75)
    Shape1.OLEFormat.Object.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    With Shape1.OLEFormat.Object.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.6000000238
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

    Dim Shape2 As Shape
    Set Shape2 = sht.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 285.75, 74.25, 111.75, 21.75)
    Shape2.OLEFormat.Object.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    With Shape2.OLEFormat.Object.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

    sht.Shapes.Range(Array(Shape1.Name, Shape2.Name)).Group
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Peh, Thanks for this. Is there a way the code wont conflict with shape names? I.e. If i wanted to create more stickies, will I have to change the macro name every time? How can I make it such that everytime I generate a sticky, it creates new ones, without conflicts of object names?

Comment: @CodeMeARiver Obviously you didn't try it. This generates a new group of 2 shapes everytime you run the code (or click the button). Obviously the shape is generated in the same place everytime, so if you don't move them around you will see only the top one.

Comment: I had tried your code. It wasn't the case that I didn't try it. I did make a mistake with your code - yes. I pasted it over my own, and it created the conflict errors as there was still some of my code left over which I missed. I should've tried yours on a blank canvas. Yours works correctly too :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, I tweaked my code a bit and solved it myself. Essentially, I had to make sure that I could grab the name of the objects correctly to group them. Take a look at the code below:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
Dim James1 As Shape
Dim James2 As Shape

Set James1= ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 285, 74.25, 112.5, 108.75)
James1.Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.6000000238
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With
  Set James2= ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 285.75, 74.25, 111.75, 21.75)
  James2.Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse

    Dim S1 As String
    Dim S2 As String

    S1 = James1.Name
    S2 = James2.Name

  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(S1, S2)).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select
```

Comment: Just a note: I recommend to avoid using `.Select` which makes your code slow and which is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks Peh. That's some handy advice!